# Castle Windsor - DependsOn doesn't work in F#?

Tags: f#, castle-windsor

Registering dependencies on a per-registration basis using `DependsOn` doesn't seem to work in F# - am I missing something?

For example, this will not work (resolution error, waiting for dependency `IChild` which is not registered):

```
module Program

open System
open Castle.Windsor
open Castle.MicroKernel.Registration

type IChild = 
    interface end

type IParent = 
    interface end

type Child () = 
    interface IChild

type Parent (child : IChild) = 
    interface IParent

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 

    let dependency = Dependency.OnValue<IChild> (Child ())

    use container = new WindsorContainer ()

    container.Register (
        Component.For<IParent>().ImplementedBy<Parent>().DependsOn(dependency)
    ) |> ignore

    let parent = container.Resolve<IParent> () //Exception due to missing dependency

    0
```

However, registering the type with the container globally works fine, e.g.

```
module Program

open System
open Castle.Windsor
open Castle.MicroKernel.Registration

type IChild = 
    interface end

type IParent = 
    interface end

type Child () = 
    interface IChild

type Parent (child : IChild) = 
    interface IParent

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 

    use container = new WindsorContainer ()

    container
        .Register(Component.For<IChild>().ImplementedBy<Child>())
        .Register(Component.For<IParent>().ImplementedBy<Parent>())
    |> ignore        

    let parent = container.Resolve<IParent> () //Works as expected

    0
```

I can see no obvious differences between the Property created by `Dependency.OnValue` in C# and in F#.

Comment: Looks fine from here based on some cursory glancing at [the docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Inline-Dependencies&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). What is the type of dependency. Are there weird overloads for the `.DependsOn()` part of the syntax?

Comment: let dependency = Property.op_Implicit (Dependency.OnValue<IChild> (Child ()))

Comment: @RubenBartelink It behaves the same for all types as far as I can see.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer That works! If you add it as an answer I'll marked it as accepted :)

Comment: @MarkWatts go ahead and answer yourself, but you have to explain why that change was needed, so I can make sure you understand ;-)

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Presumably because the desired overload DependsOn accepts a Dependency but Dependency.OnValue<T> returns a Property and F# will not perform the implicit conversion automatically as C# would (I assumed Property inherited Dependency which it does not). I can't tell which overload of DependsOn F# does invoke though, none of them look like a match!

Comment: That's correct. Hover over the DependsOn() call to see which overload is being used.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Ha, I missed that one when I looked through the overloads. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Mauricio Scheffer, the problem is that `Dependency.OnValue<T>` returns a Property and F# will not use the implicit conversion defined on Property automatically to call `DependsOn(Dependency)`. Rather, it will call `DependsOn(obj)` which is meant to be used for anonymous types.

Changing the code so that the dependency is created like this fixes the issue:

```
let dependency = Property.op_Implicit(Dependency.OnValue<IChild>(Child ()))
```